# What means syntax like the following: @var=("","")

Tags: php

I'm using eclipse and I put a script into my project. In a config-file there are php-statements like the following:

```
@ftp_mode=(0,0,0);
@ftp_user=("","","");
```

Eclipse marks them as syntax errors but everything works. So I want to know if this is an error and if not what means it? It looks like an assignment, but there's no `$`-sign ...

Thanks in advance.

Regards Binabik

Comment: If you open a C++ in the PHP editor, it will give you errors as well ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a config file for an app it's likely that the app parses the file internally so the syntax won't matter. It would generate a parse error in standard PHP syntax.

Comment: +1 this is the right answer, mine merely stated what the @ does usually in php.

Comment: Ok, I was only irritated because the rest of the file looks like php but it seems that the file doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

`@` is used just before an expression to make the interpreter suppress errors that would be generated from that expression.

Source: wiki

Well... this might not be the case here, `@` is used usually before function calls to suppress error messages from that function. As Clive pointed out, it might be some custom config file format. Also, you say "In a config-file there are php-statements"... is that file a `.php` file? If not why are you saying these are php statements?

Comment: I think not in this instance. That isn't valid PHP. - must be some custom config file format.

Comment: I've just run that code and it doesn't surpress any errors, the error is `Parse error: syntax error...`...the syntax is simply invalid

Comment: "Source: wiki" *Which* wiki, and why no link?